# How to test google search button

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I am learning software testing using "watin". Currently i want to record a test on how to search for the word:Unit testing on google.I installed the developer addon on my IE and
use it to get the google's search textbox  and button name.When i run my test and
type the search term i received this errorMessage:Failed First_test threw exception:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using WatiN.Core;

namespace Web_project_test
{
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void First_test()
    {
        IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com");  
        ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("Unit testing");
        ie.Button(Find.ByValue("btnk")).Click();  
        bool Expected_Result = ie.Text.Contains("Unit testing");  
        Assert.IsTrue(Expected_Result);
    }  
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your code. And the exception.

Comment: i have edited to include my code

Answer (score 1):

This is an example shown on Watin.org at http://watin.org/

```
using (var browser = new IE("http://www.google.co.uk"))
  {
    browser.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
    browser.Button(Find.ByName("btnK")).Click();

    Assert.IsTrue(browser.ContainsText("WatiN"));
  }
```

Update :

The line of code **ie.Button(Find.ByValue("btnk")).Click();** does not look correct for because the id of search button on google.com is **btnk** and value is **"Google Search"**

This might be the issue you test fail please correct the line as: **ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnk")).Click();**

Comment: @HatScoft, i run the test by holding on the Ctrl key and Click on the url,it direct me to the right page and the search results are display, but my test class don't show whether test has pass or failed.

Comment: Let me try it will let you know in 20 mins

Comment: i got this Message i when run the test in current context:No tests were run becasuse no tests are loaded or the selected tests are disable

Comment: I tried the updated code advised by me in the post and it works  without any errors the only difference is i used ReSharper to Run the Test

Comment: Did you create your class as demostrated at this link:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OPzN5Lq4-9Y